# Perl Tk: Canvas dynamic updating

Tags: perl, canvas, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to animate the results of a mathematical process in a 2D canvas with Tk. I've decided to do it with Tk and not SDL because right now i'm working with both Linux and Windows machines and Strawberry Perl doesn't compile proberly in windows, whil Tk is up on both pcs.

What i would like to do with Tk is that:

1)Popping up the canvas while my program is working out the coordinates of the points i would like to draw.

2)Drawing them instantly into the canvas without waiting for the process to reach the end

It's actually a simple animation, where a bunch of points moves around the Canvas while my script updates their coordinates.

Here you have a code snippet i've been writing so far for a single point:

```
use Tk;

#calcuate the coordinate of a single point
$x=10;
$y=10;
$top = MainWindow->new();

# create a canvas widget
$canvas = $top->Canvas(width => 600, height => 400) -> pack();

# For example, let's create 1 point inside the canvas
$canvas->create ('oval', $x, $y, $x+3, $y+3, -fill=>"black");  # fill color of object

MainLoop;
```

The problem with the above code is that i would like to add my 'math' script inside it in order to update the $x and $y coordinates above (with some sort of for/while cycle) without shutting down the original canvas, by obtaining a single point moving all around it (atually there are more points i'm supposed to display but that's a minor detail).
FYI, using a simple for cycle embedding the ''Mainloop'' directive doesn't fix the problem.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Maybe try an event loop like [`AnyEvent::Impl::Tk`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::Impl::Tk) ?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [Mastering Perl/Tk](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565927162.do), chapter 15 "Anatomy of the MainLoop":

### Option 1: use your own `MainLoop` implementation

```perl
use Tk qw(:eventtypes);

while (Tk::MainWindow->Count) {
    # process events - but don't block waiting for them
    DoOneEvent(ALL_EVENTS | DONT_WAIT);

    # your update implementation goes here
}
```

### Option 2: use a repeat timer event

Later in the chapter it is stated that `DoOneEvent()` isn't really necessary for most stuff. You could use timer events instead, e.g.

```perl
my $update = sub {
    # your update implementation goes here
};

# run update every 50ms
$top->repeat(50, $update);

MainLoop;
```

Comment: Stefan, thanks a lot. I've implemented solution nr.2 as suggested by you an now everything works like a charm. I will follow up with a code snippet of what figured out as final solution to the original problem. Thanks again man

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

As per Stefan Becker suggested option nr.2, here is what has finally fixed the problem:

```
use Tk:

$top = MainWindow->new();

# create a canvas widget
$canvas = $top->Canvas(width => 600, 
                        height => 400,
                        background => 'black') -> pack();

$x=300; 
$y=200; 

my $update = sub {
    $canvas->delete('all'); #unquote this line if you don't want the original point positions to be drawn in the canvas. Viceversa
    $x=$x+(-5+rand(10)); #white noise
    $y=$y-(-5+rand(10)); #white noise
    $canvas->create ('oval', $x , $y , $x+5, $y+5, -fill=>"red"); 
    };  

    $top->repeat(50, $update); 

MainLoop;
```

I've just added the statement $canvas->delete('all') at the beginning of the updating loop in order to draw just actual points and not the history.

Comment: It would be far more efficient to use the canvas move command to move the oval than to delete and re-create it.  Not a python user, but I know it can be done.